# Android loop on button click until argument not true

Tags: android, loops, while-loop

So I'm goofing around in Android Studio trying to set the button loop until counter<=3. However, if I click the button in the emulator it just skips to the statements after "if", why is that? Does the button do the things I specified in *while* in rapid succession instead of 1 time per click? How do I fix it?
Anyway here is the excerpt code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    TextView myTextView;
    int counter = 0;

    public void onClick(View v) {
        while(counter<=3){
            myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
            myTextView.setText("Button clicked");
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter==4){
            myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
            myTextView.setText("hello");}

    }
```

Comment: You want to show the "Hello" message when the button is pressed fourth time?

Comment: for this example, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as you thought, the while loop just executes until counter is no longer <= 3. Then if(counter==4) is true, and the if statement executes...

```
button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        TextView myTextView;
        int counter = 0;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (counter == 4) {
                myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
                myTextView.setText("hello");
            } else {
                myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
                myTextView.setText("Button clicked");
                counter++;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: ok it works now but i have one other question if you don't mind; when i do it in normal JAVA in NetBeans it works as i intended, why? i used WHILE first and then IF both with JOptionPane.showMessageDialog as statements

Comment: I don't fully understand the intention, so I can't really answer why it works. But the while loop will execute till counter = 4, which at that point, the if statement will pass and execute.

Comment: In android studio if i try my first code, if i press my button the textField immediately changes to "hello" instead of showing "button clicked" 3 times and then "hello".However in NetBeans with JOptionpane.showMessageDialog method it shows "button clicked" on 3 consecutive button clicks and then it shows "hello". How is that?

Comment: I havn't used NetBeans, but the difference I think is that here you're changing the textView to say "Button clicked" but the loop executes so fast that all you see is the end result: "hello". You can see the loop executes if you do a Log instead of changing the textView.

Comment: so i tested the loop with system.out.println and added a wait command after each task in the while loop. It appears that setText doesnt work during the loop but system.out.println correctly prints the value counter i have given it.. this is confusing...

Comment: Just don't use a while loop, it doesn't make sense with what you're trying to do. Do if/else, so only one thing happens each time it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will execute over and over even though it is only called once (per click). That's why it's called a loop. You need to change it to an if statement  - will execute once per click.

Also, I'd recommend declaring your TextView and counter globally at the top of your activity instead of inside your click listener. Then assign your TextView in onCreate()